# Parallelise code with pthread and semaphore

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I need to make this code working in parallel using pthreads and semaphores using C. It is supposed to work with up to 16 threads.

This is the code that is working in serial:

```
    for(counter = numberOfPoints; counter > numberOfClusters; counter--){

        double minimunValue = 9999999999999;

        for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < counter; j++){
                if((distanceMatrix[i][j] < minimunValue) && (i != j)){

                    minimunValue = distanceMatrix[i][j];
                    cityA = i;
                    cityB = j;
                }
            }
        }


        for(j = 0; j < counter; j++){
            if(j == cityA) 
                distanceMatrix[cityA][j] = 0;

            if(distanceMatrix[cityA][j] > distanceMatrix[cityB][j]){
                distanceMatrix[cityA][j] = distanceMatrix[cityB][j];
                distanceMatrix[j][cityA] = distanceMatrix[cityB][j];
            }
        }


        for(i = 0; i < counter; i++){
            for(j = cityB; j < counter - 1; j++){
                distanceMatrix[i][j] = distanceMatrix[i][j+1];
            }
        }

        for(i = cityB;i < (counter-1);i++){
            distanceMatrix[i] = distanceMatrix[i+1];  

        }
        //more code here but it doesn't matter for now
    }
```

What I did:

I created 2 semaphores like this:

```
sem_t* mutex;
sem_t* lock;

    //inside main()
    int rc = sem_unlink("mutex");
    if (rc)
        perror("sem_unlink mutex");

    rc = sem_unlink("barrier");
    if (rc)
        perror("sem_unlink barrier");

    numberOfClusters = atoi(argv[2]);
    numberOfThreads = atoi(argv[3]);

    mutex = sem_open("mutex", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, numberOfThreads);
    lock = sem_open("barrier", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, numberOfThreads);
```

After I implemented a barrier as follows:

```
void barrier() {
    sem_wait(mutex);
    if (threadsWorking == (numberOfThreads - 1)) {
        threadsWorking = 0;
        sem_post(mutex);

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < (numberOfThreads - 1); i++) {
            sem_post(lock);
        }
    } else {
        threadsWorking++;
        sem_post(mutex);
        sem_wait(lock);
    }
}
```

Now, the function that will be called on each thread:

```
void *thread_clustering(void *thread_id){
    int i, j;
    int thread_counter = thread_id;

    //this is the 2nd for, this part is working fine using pthreads
    for(i = thread_counter; i < counter; i += numberOfThreads){
        if(distanceMatrix[cityA][i] > distanceMatrix[cityB][i]){
            distanceMatrix[cityA][i] = distanceMatrix[cityB][i];
            distanceMatrix[i][cityA] = distanceMatrix[cityB][i];
        }
    }

    barrier();

    //this commented code is about the 3rd for, but it is not working as I want
    // for(i = thread_counter; i < counter; i += numberOfThreads){
    //     for(j = cityB; j < counter - 1; j++){
    //         distanceMatrix[i][j] = distanceMatrix[i][j+1];
    //     }
    // }

    // barrier();
}
```

and this is how I think my final code will be after all parallelisation:

```
for(counter = numberOfPoints; counter > numberOfClusters; counter--){
    for(i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL, thread_clustering, (void *)i);
    }  

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    } 
    //more code here
}
```

So, anyone have any idea on what should I do to put all the first code inside thread_clustering?

Regards!

**EDIT:**

This is part of the Hierarchical Clustering Algorithm, described as above:

1. Start with n clusters containing one object
2. Find the most similar pair of clusters Ci and Cj from the proximity
   matrix and merge them into a single cluster
3. Update the proximity matrix (reduce its order by one, by replacing the individual clusters with the merged cluster)
4. Repeat steps (2) e (3) until a single cluster is obtained (i.e. N-1 times)

Comment: `double minimunValue = 9999999999999;` has it all: Implicit conversion, magic numbers, possibly misleading...

Comment: which exact problem do have with the code?

Comment: @EOF it is just a number, in this for I'm looking for the smallest value in a matrix

Comment: @4386427 I was asked to implement Hierarchical Clustering algorithm in parallel, this part of the code is the critical part I couldn't parallelise by myself

Comment: @Claudio - can you add some description of the problem you are trying to solve (in serial) and how you plan to divide the work between the threads.

Comment: @4386427 I edited the question with some more information

Answer (score 0):

For the first set of nested `for()` loops, that finds the closest pair of cities, it's easy enough to parallelise it in the same way as your other loops, so that each thread finds the closest pair of cities within its part of the search:

```
double minimumValue = DBL_MAX;

for (i = thread_counter; i < counter; i += numberOfThreads) {
    for (j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
        if ((distanceMatrix[i][j] < minimumValue) && (i != j)) {
            minimumValue = distanceMatrix[i][j];
            cityA = i;
            cityB = j;
        }
    }
}
```

But for the remainder of the function you need to use the closest set of cities across all threads.  So, you need an array of "closest cities", one for each thread, and have each thread store into that array after the first loop:

```
closest[thread_counter].distance = minimumValue;
closest[thread_counter].cityA = cityA;
closest[thread_counter].cityB = cityB;
```

Now you need to wait for the other threads to store their values, then pick the smallest one:

```
barrier();

minimumValue = DBL_MAX;

for (i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    if (minimumValue > closest[i].distance) {
        minimumValue = closest[i].distance)
        cityA = closest[i].cityA;
        cityB = closest[i].cityB;
    }
}
```

(Note that we need to re-set `minimumValue` to the largest value again so that all threads always choose the same city pair in the same order if there's multiple options with the same distance).

Note that your `barrier()` implementation has a problem - you should be initialising the `mutex` semaphore to the value `1` (so that only the first thread that waits on it can proceed until its posted), and the `lock` semaphore should be initialised to the value `0` (so that all threads that wait on it are blocked until it is posted).  The initial value of the semaphore is the last parameter to `sem_open()`.